# Assiging timeout/break on multiple observables in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, settimeout

Bear with me on this one cause this one is a bit tricky for me to explain.
So I have multiple observables assigned, say:-

```
var self = this;
self.amount = ko.observableArray();
self.data0 = ko.observable([10,11,12]);
self.data1 = ko.observable([1,2,3]);
self.data2 = ko.observable([3,4,5]);
self.data3 = ko.observable([6,7,8]);
self.data4 = ko.observable([9,10,11]);
```

And there is some button that changes the value on each of them with the following function (what this functions does isn't really important, it's merely to show that there is some change going on in the observables)

```
self.bindOneByOne = function(){
    var self = this;
    var i = 0;
    while(self['data' + i]){
        for(var j = 0, len = self['data'+i]().length; j < len; j++){
            self['data'+i]()[j] *= 2; 
        }
        self.amount.push(i);
        i++;
        }
};
```

Now what I'm wanting to do is to display the changes as it happens in the UI side, one at a time (first self.data0 and then data1 and so on..) when I call a function (click on a button in this case)

My attempt for that behavior so far:-

```
self.changeValues = function(){
    var i = 0;
    while(self['data' + i]){
        setTimeout(self['data' +i].valueHasMutated,1000);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Shouldn't my code first bind self.data0 first and shouldn't it immediately reflect on my UI? Currently, I'm only seeing changes all at once which is not the behavior I wanted.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyEMc/) for what I'm trying to do. (Click on Populate/Change to populate the data and change it after it's been populated...and then Mutate to see the changes on the UI side. You can also see that the data is indeed changing when you press Populate/Change button if you check your console prior to clicking on Mutate button)

Comment: Changes on the UI side will be seen immediately when data gets populated. Since you are binding the data to the UI..
<p data-bind="text:$data"></p>
That is the advantage given by knockout..

Comment: I do want the changes to be displayed but if you look at my code I'm binding them one observable at a time (in `while` loop with `timeout`. First `self.data0` and then `self.data1` and then self.data2..you get the point. And I would like the UI to do the same too. Reflect changes one at a time instead of all at once on a single function call.

Comment: First, settimeout is being used with timeout as 1000. Which means, everything will be executed after 1sec. May be you want to add i*1000 in the timeout fn. 

Secondly, bindOneByOne is not having any timeout so it just fills the data and since it is binded, it gets reflected automatically.

Comment: omg. yes!! Thank you. I was completely forgetting about i*1000 on timeout. I have been trying to get this thing working for 2 days now. bindOneByOne however, is doing what I intended.

Answer (score 0):

The key with the timeout is to capture the loop values (i and J) in a closure with the use of an IEFE(immediately invoked function execution)

```
                for(var j = 0, len = self['data'+i]().length; j < len; j++){
                    (function(){
                        //this captures the item to set using the current value of i and J
                        var itemToSet = self['data'+i]()[j];
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            console.log('itemToSet',itemToSet());
                            itemToSet(itemToSet() * 2);
                        },1000*(i+1));
                    })() //the () brackets immediately invoke this function that is also in brackets
                }
                self.amount.push(i);
```

I've created a fiddle to show it working, you only need the 1 button to show it really, I have just made the second button update each item individually, rather than all values in the array that the first button does.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jiggle/hxvFz/)

Hope it helps.